How do I run a raspberry pi os lite guest virtual machine on a kvm hypervisor in debian bookworm
I converted the downloaded 2024-07-04-raspios-bookworm-arm64-lite.img file to 2024-07-04-raspios-bookworm-arm64-lite.qcow2 and executed:
virt-install \
  --import \
  --name raspios-vm \
  --ram 2048 \
  --vcpus 2 \
  --disk path=~/Downloads/2024-07-04-raspios-bookworm-arm64-lite.qcow2,format=qcow2 \
  --os-variant debian12 \
  --network network=default \
  --graphics spice \
  --console pty,target_type=serial

I am on a Debian Bookworm desktop using kvm.
Problem: it hangs after saying "Booting from hard disk" and does not continue. How do  I resolve this?
I also tried it via the gui virt-manager and it had the same results.
